# Return single object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I've been trying to do this several days ago.

I want to make a query that gets all the businesses that are registered in one city, after that for each Business I'd like to get all products in business and finally store it onto a new object and send it as a response to front end.

This is the code I'm using:

```js
router.get('/app/list-all-products-city', async(req, res, next) => {
  var AddProduct;
  var Result;
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    _business = await Business.find({
      businessCity: 'Departamento de Cochabamba'
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('hubo un error, algo malio sal');
  }
  try {
    for (i in _business) {
      let Products = await Product.find({
        productInBusiness: _business[i]['_id']
      });
      for (index in Products) {
        if (Products.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
          console.log(Products[index].productName);
          AddProduct = {
            AddProduct,
            ...Products
          };
        }
      }
    }
    res.json(AddProduct);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('hubo un error, algo malio sal');
  }
});
```

but unfortunately I'm getting a nested object which is this one:

```js
{
  "0": {
    "productStatus": 1,
    "productTags": "2020-08-03 23:14",
    "productPerCentPromo": 0,
    "productCreationDate": "2020-08-03 23:14",
    "_id": "5f2a183a8360400063020c8f",
    "productName": "Util",
    "productInBusiness": "5f2a15c38360400063020c8d",
    "productCategory": "5f1bad9ebbf8a71eb730baf7",
    "productSubCategory": "5f2a16eb8360400063020c8e",
    "productDetails": "Limpieza de superficies de cocina ",
    "productUnitSale": "Botella",
    "productSalePrice": 25,
    "productStock": 50,
    "ProductImage001": "A1LmqJaHtXC6KETKxehjf.jpg",
    "ProductImage002": "gYsYqHMvP79eBcFUjeYqxz.jpg",
    "ProductImage003": "trpgfZPfX41rbJh5z7H1nr.jpg",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "AddProduct": {
    "0": {
      "productStatus": 1,
      "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
      "productPerCentPromo": 0,
      "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
      "_id": "5f272901569c9700523bbcca",
      "productName": "Zapatón de lana",
      "productInBusiness": "5f2723f8569c9700523bbcc6",
      "productCategory": "5f1bb0f4bbf8a71eb730baf9",
      "productSubCategory": "5f26e548569c9700523bbcbe",
      "productDetails": "Zapatones de lana tejidos a crochet, con suela antideslizante.",
      "productUnitSale": "Par",
      "productSalePrice": 40,
      "productStock": 3,
      "ProductImage001": "ufyagH39yatG1ypQDNTPG8.jpg",
      "ProductImage002": "dRCyVqRFsPaYssUBp5Cugo.jpg",
      "ProductImage003": "erMXW5n1epo11CEyASjCM.jpg",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "AddProduct": {
      "0": {
        "productStatus": 1,
        "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
        "productPerCentPromo": 0,
        "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
        "_id": "5f2716f1569c9700523bbcc4",
        "productName": "Latitude 3400 Business Laptop",
        "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
        "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
        "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
        "productDetails": "Dell Latitude 3000 3400 14\" Notebook - 1920 x 1080 - Core i5 i5-8265U - 8 GB RAM - 256 GB SSD - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit - Intel UHD Graphics 620 - English (US) Keyboard - Bluetooth",
        "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
        "productSalePrice": 10455,
        "productStock": 3,
        "ProductImage001": "xAW2zhRVrPskVCxHf23L3X.jpg",
        "ProductImage002": "c3nZcJiaTtNUyV5DdMymtd.jpg",
        "ProductImage003": "fn5Qi86mexerHosVwy9c9Z.jpg",
        "__v": 0
      },
      "1": {
        "productStatus": 1,
        "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
        "productPerCentPromo": 0,
        "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
        "_id": "5f271ace569c9700523bbcc5",
        "productName": "Apple MacBook Pro (13 pulgadas)",
        "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
        "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
        "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
        "productDetails": "Tenth-generation quad-core Intel Core i5 processor Brilliant Retina display with True Tone technology Backlit Magic Keyboard Touch Bar and Touch ID Intel Iris Plus Graphics Ultrafast SSD Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports",
        "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
        "productSalePrice": 135940,
        "productStock": 5,
        "ProductImage001": "wn2d18DCSbzRkxG4ZZaBY2.jpg",
        "ProductImage002": "wxtujJ3YLxbY2UjnXzujP6.jpg",
        "ProductImage003": "bJS75Zzi4HSskff9i17Z4D.jpg",
        "__v": 0
      },
      "2": {
        "productStatus": 1,
        "productTags": "2020-08-03 23:14",
        "productPerCentPromo": 0,
        "productCreationDate": "2020-08-03 23:14",
        "_id": "5f2a2d618360400063020c90",
        "productName": "2020 HP Stream 11.6 pulgadas portátil, Intel Atom x5 E8000 hasta 2.0 GHz",
        "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
        "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
        "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
        "productDetails": "【Office 365 Included】One year of Microsoft Office 365 included ($70 Value). 11.6 inch diagonal HD SVA anti-glare WLED-backlit (1366 x 768), Intel HD Graphics 【Quad-Core Atom x5-E8000】Intel Atom x5-E8000 (1.04 GHz base frequency, up to 2.0 GHz, 2 MB cache, 4 cores), 2-cell, 37.69 Wh Li-ion, up to 12 hours battery life mixed-use 【High Speed】RAM is upgraded to 4GB DDR3L memory for multitasking Adequate high-bandwidth RAM to smoothly run multiple applications and browser tabs all at once 【Enormous Space】Hard Drive is upgraded to 64GB eMMC provides massive storage space for huge files, so that you can store important digital data and work your way through it with ease. Enhance the overall performance of the laptop for business, student, daily usage 【Authorized NexiGo Bundle】 Bundled with NexiGo 32GB MicroSD Card, offers cost-effective portable solution instantly boosting available storage space for your laptop, Authorized Sellers ONLY. 2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1, 1 x USB 3.1 Type-C, 1 x HDMI 1.4, 1 x headphone/microphone combo",
        "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
        "productSalePrice": 2500,
        "productStock": 10,
        "ProductImage001": "nduaWJqGGVvB9jHMTh3sna.jpg",
        "ProductImage002": "ih3XJ8NXuqiaBJonGoKcDP.jpg",
        "ProductImage003": "vuY1GtAP4pmcduD7YwZpCb.jpg",
        "__v": 0
      },
      "AddProduct": {
        "0": {
          "productStatus": 1,
          "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
          "productPerCentPromo": 0,
          "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
          "_id": "5f2716f1569c9700523bbcc4",
          "productName": "Latitude 3400 Business Laptop",
          "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
          "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
          "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
          "productDetails": "Dell Latitude 3000 3400 14\" Notebook - 1920 x 1080 - Core i5 i5-8265U - 8 GB RAM - 256 GB SSD - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit - Intel UHD Graphics 620 - English (US) Keyboard - Bluetooth",
          "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
          "productSalePrice": 10455,
          "productStock": 3,
          "ProductImage001": "xAW2zhRVrPskVCxHf23L3X.jpg",
          "ProductImage002": "c3nZcJiaTtNUyV5DdMymtd.jpg",
          "ProductImage003": "fn5Qi86mexerHosVwy9c9Z.jpg",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "1": {
          "productStatus": 1,
          "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
          "productPerCentPromo": 0,
          "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
          "_id": "5f271ace569c9700523bbcc5",
          "productName": "Apple MacBook Pro (13 pulgadas)",
          "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
          "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
          "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
          "productDetails": "Tenth-generation quad-core Intel Core i5 processor Brilliant Retina display with True Tone technology Backlit Magic Keyboard Touch Bar and Touch ID Intel Iris Plus Graphics Ultrafast SSD Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports",
          "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
          "productSalePrice": 135940,
          "productStock": 5,
          "ProductImage001": "wn2d18DCSbzRkxG4ZZaBY2.jpg",
          "ProductImage002": "wxtujJ3YLxbY2UjnXzujP6.jpg",
          "ProductImage003": "bJS75Zzi4HSskff9i17Z4D.jpg",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "2": {
          "productStatus": 1,
          "productTags": "2020-08-03 23:14",
          "productPerCentPromo": 0,
          "productCreationDate": "2020-08-03 23:14",
          "_id": "5f2a2d618360400063020c90",
          "productName": "2020 HP Stream 11.6 pulgadas portátil, Intel Atom x5 E8000 hasta 2.0 GHz",
          "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
          "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
          "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
          "productDetails": "【Office 365 Included】One year of Microsoft Office 365 included ($70 Value). 11.6 inch diagonal HD SVA anti-glare WLED-backlit (1366 x 768), Intel HD Graphics 【Quad-Core Atom x5-E8000】Intel Atom x5-E8000 (1.04 GHz base frequency, up to 2.0 GHz, 2 MB cache, 4 cores), 2-cell, 37.69 Wh Li-ion, up to 12 hours battery life mixed-use 【High Speed】RAM is upgraded to 4GB DDR3L memory for multitasking Adequate high-bandwidth RAM to smoothly run multiple applications and browser tabs all at once 【Enormous Space】Hard Drive is upgraded to 64GB eMMC provides massive storage space for huge files, so that you can store important digital data and work your way through it with ease. Enhance the overall performance of the laptop for business, student, daily usage 【Authorized NexiGo Bundle】 Bundled with NexiGo 32GB MicroSD Card, offers cost-effective portable solution instantly boosting available storage space for your laptop, Authorized Sellers ONLY. 2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1, 1 x USB 3.1 Type-C, 1 x HDMI 1.4, 1 x headphone/microphone combo",
          "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
          "productSalePrice": 2500,
          "productStock": 10,
          "ProductImage001": "nduaWJqGGVvB9jHMTh3sna.jpg",
          "ProductImage002": "ih3XJ8NXuqiaBJonGoKcDP.jpg",
          "ProductImage003": "vuY1GtAP4pmcduD7YwZpCb.jpg",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "AddProduct": {
          "0": {
            "productStatus": 1,
            "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
            "productPerCentPromo": 0,
            "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
            "_id": "5f2716f1569c9700523bbcc4",
            "productName": "Latitude 3400 Business Laptop",
            "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
            "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
            "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
            "productDetails": "Dell Latitude 3000 3400 14\" Notebook - 1920 x 1080 - Core i5 i5-8265U - 8 GB RAM - 256 GB SSD - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit - Intel UHD Graphics 620 - English (US) Keyboard - Bluetooth",
            "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
            "productSalePrice": 10455,
            "productStock": 3,
            "ProductImage001": "xAW2zhRVrPskVCxHf23L3X.jpg",
            "ProductImage002": "c3nZcJiaTtNUyV5DdMymtd.jpg",
            "ProductImage003": "fn5Qi86mexerHosVwy9c9Z.jpg",
            "__v": 0
          },
          "1": {
            "productStatus": 1,
            "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
            "productPerCentPromo": 0,
            "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
            "_id": "5f271ace569c9700523bbcc5",
            "productName": "Apple MacBook Pro (13 pulgadas)",
            "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
            "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
            "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
            "productDetails": "Tenth-generation quad-core Intel Core i5 processor Brilliant Retina display with True Tone technology Backlit Magic Keyboard Touch Bar and Touch ID Intel Iris Plus Graphics Ultrafast SSD Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports",
            "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
            "productSalePrice": 135940,
            "productStock": 5,
            "ProductImage001": "wn2d18DCSbzRkxG4ZZaBY2.jpg",
            "ProductImage002": "wxtujJ3YLxbY2UjnXzujP6.jpg",
            "ProductImage003": "bJS75Zzi4HSskff9i17Z4D.jpg",
            "__v": 0
          },
          "2": {
            "productStatus": 1,
            "productTags": "2020-08-03 23:14",
            "productPerCentPromo": 0,
            "productCreationDate": "2020-08-03 23:14",
            "_id": "5f2a2d618360400063020c90",
            "productName": "2020 HP Stream 11.6 pulgadas portátil, Intel Atom x5 E8000 hasta 2.0 GHz",
            "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
            "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
            "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
            "productDetails": "【Office 365 Included】One year of Microsoft Office 365 included ($70 Value). 11.6 inch diagonal HD SVA anti-glare WLED-backlit (1366 x 768), Intel HD Graphics 【Quad-Core Atom x5-E8000】Intel Atom x5-E8000 (1.04 GHz base frequency, up to 2.0 GHz, 2 MB cache, 4 cores), 2-cell, 37.69 Wh Li-ion, up to 12 hours battery life mixed-use 【High Speed】RAM is upgraded to 4GB DDR3L memory for multitasking Adequate high-bandwidth RAM to smoothly run multiple applications and browser tabs all at once 【Enormous Space】Hard Drive is upgraded to 64GB eMMC provides massive storage space for huge files, so that you can store important digital data and work your way through it with ease. Enhance the overall performance of the laptop for business, student, daily usage 【Authorized NexiGo Bundle】 Bundled with NexiGo 32GB MicroSD Card, offers cost-effective portable solution instantly boosting available storage space for your laptop, Authorized Sellers ONLY. 2 x USB 3.1 Gen 1, 1 x USB 3.1 Type-C, 1 x HDMI 1.4, 1 x headphone/microphone combo",
            "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
            "productSalePrice": 2500,
            "productStock": 10,
            "ProductImage001": "nduaWJqGGVvB9jHMTh3sna.jpg",
            "ProductImage002": "ih3XJ8NXuqiaBJonGoKcDP.jpg",
            "ProductImage003": "vuY1GtAP4pmcduD7YwZpCb.jpg",
            "__v": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you have to return array of object.

Comment: I tried several combinations... even I used  one whit Object.assing and It didn't work

AddProduct = Object.assign({AddProduct}, Products);

and no success... Honestly I'm Getting Crazy with it...

Comment: @MarceSanchezMelgar which DB library is used here? have you explored eager loading type of options in DB library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error: Here adding same data again and again creating nested object.

```
  AddProduct = {
            AddProduct,
            ...Products
       };
```

example :

```
  var a = {"ch":"a"}
  var b = { "test": "a" }
  a = {
     a,
     ...b
  }
  a = {
     a,
   ...b
}
```

Instead add the data in array and send it.

```
    for (index in Products) {
        if (Products.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
          console.log(Products[index].productName);
          AddProduct.push(Products)        
          };
        }
      }
    }

output :
[ {
"0": {
    "productStatus": 1,
    "productTags": "2020-08-03 23:14",
    "productPerCentPromo": 0,
    "productCreationDate": "2020-08-03 23:14",
    "_id": "5f2a183a8360400063020c8f",
    "productName": "Util",
    "productInBusiness": "5f2a15c38360400063020c8d",
    "productCategory": "5f1bad9ebbf8a71eb730baf7",
    "productSubCategory": "5f2a16eb8360400063020c8e",
    "productDetails": "Limpieza de superficies de cocina ",
    "productUnitSale": "Botella",
    "productSalePrice": 25,
    "productStock": 50,
    "ProductImage001": "A1LmqJaHtXC6KETKxehjf.jpg",
    "ProductImage002": "gYsYqHMvP79eBcFUjeYqxz.jpg",
    "ProductImage003": "trpgfZPfX41rbJh5z7H1nr.jpg",
    "__v": 0
  },
"1": {
        "productStatus": 1,
        "productTags": "2020-08-02 14:16",
        "productPerCentPromo": 0,
        "productCreationDate": "2020-08-02 14:16",
        "_id": "5f271ace569c9700523bbcc5",
        "productName": "Apple MacBook Pro (13 pulgadas)",
        "productInBusiness": "5f2715c9569c9700523bbcc3",
        "productCategory": "5f1bb62abbf8a71eb730bafb",
        "productSubCategory": "5f1c861e72a9f59686f5fd68",
        "productDetails": "Tenth-generation quad-core Intel Core i5 processor Brilliant Retina display with True Tone technology Backlit Magic Keyboard Touch Bar and Touch ID Intel Iris Plus Graphics Ultrafast SSD Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports",
        "productUnitSale": "Unidad",
        "productSalePrice": 135940,
        "productStock": 5,
        "ProductImage001": "wn2d18DCSbzRkxG4ZZaBY2.jpg",
        "ProductImage002": "wxtujJ3YLxbY2UjnXzujP6.jpg",
        "ProductImage003": "bJS75Zzi4HSskff9i17Z4D.jpg",
        "__v": 0
      },
]
```

Comment: Thanks, yet it did't worked.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: var AddProduct = []

Comment: make it array and use it.

Comment: Great matey!! It did work, 
Actually I had to make a little modificacion on the puhs line:

AddProduct.push(Products[index]);

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change

```
console.log(Products[index].productName);
          AddProduct = {
            AddProduct,
            ...Products
          };
```

to

```
console.log(Products[index].productName);
          AddProduct = {
            ...AddProduct,
            ...Products
          };
```